# ubuntu haskell ghci 7.4.1 could not find module "System.Random"

Tags: haskell

When I tried to load a .hs in ghci, it failed on the line:

```
import System.Random
```

Message:

```
Could not find module `System.Random'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I remember it worked yesterday and all of a sudden today it does not work.
This problem only occurs on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, GHCi 7.4.1 , when i tried this on windows haskell platform and other linux machines i worked.

I tried to use

```
 sudo apt-get remove ghc
 sudo apt-get install ghc
```

to remove and re install ghc, but however the problem persists.

Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Do you have `random` package installed? Try `ghc-pkg list random`

Comment: i tried typing that in terminal, i got: /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d

Comment: I tried to look for files with "random" in files names, but found none. Sorry Im really newbie to these things, what should I do?

Comment: GHC no longer ships with the `random` package, so with newer GHCs (since 7.2), you have to install `random` with the distro package manager or with `cabal-install` yourself.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you know why GHC no longer ships with this package?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You must install the [random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) package. You can probably get it from your package manager (as something like `libghc-random-dev` or similar), or you may `cabal install random`.

**Edit in 2021** These days, `cabal install` is not the way. Instead, use `cabal init` to create a package and list `random` in your `build-depends` field. Compilation can be performed with `cabal build` (just build) or `cabal run` (to execute the result); interactive use is available via `cabal repl`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply, I solved the problem by first installing cabal and update the package list 
`sudo apt-get install cabal-install
cabal update`
then I was able to install the random package with
`cabal install random`