# How can I draw that number of cards from a deck in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, blackjack

In this program , I wanted to ask the user about number of cards and draw that number of cards from a deck (see below) and tell the user the cards and the
"total" of those cards. In this case, I mean a blackjack count of up to 21, with
counts over 21 returning Nothing. A blackjack count counts 2-10 as its face value, jacks,
queens and kings count as 10 and aces count as 1 or 11. I need two functions:
`drawHand :: Int ->Deck ->([Card],Deck)` and `totalCards :: [Card] ->Maybe Int`

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Random


drawHand :: Int -> Deck -> ([Card], Deck)

totalCards :: [Card] -> Maybe Int

main = do
    putStrLn "How many cards?"
    Random :: MonadRandom m => Deck-> m Deck
    Random ran = runRVar (shuffle deck) StdRandom
    Random <- getLine
    putStrLn "Hand of [] totalCards: " ++ totalCards
```

error:

```
Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Random’
Perhaps you meant Data.Ratio (from base-4.9.0.0)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: the error is telling you that GHC cannot find `Data.Random` - there is a `Sytem.Random` in the `random` package - maybe you wanted that?

Comment: for the probably more pressing and intersting question about your two functions: what did you try so far? Any starting point?

Comment: one guess: `totalCards [] = Nothing` and `totalCards xs = Just (length xs)`? ... no clue - you did not give your definitions for `Card` and `Deck` (I guess `type Deck = [Card]` because of `shuffle`?)

Comment: @Daniel Wagner - I think this question would have been closed eventually but I don't think this is really a duplicate the one you linked

Comment: @Carsten Can you say why not? The error is word-for-word identical, even down to *which module* it can't find.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think the random-stuff is only the very last step in this and I think the user did only include the error as it was the only hint the compiler gave - the main problem seem to be those two functions - yes the user is basically asking us probably for the homework - don't want to argue though - that's why I did not (vote to) reopen it

Comment: @Carsten It is the asker's responsibility to identify what question they mean to ask. If you want to make it the reader's responsibility, and expand the question away from the problem-as-stated to the problem-in-full, then I'm fine with that, but the resolution is still a close (this time for not being targeted enough). So it seems like "close as duplicate" is *at least as good* an outcome as the other options -- as at least it helps them with one problem instead of none.

Comment: @DanielWagner fine - as I said I don't want to argue here - I'm just trying to help out (it's that time of the year again it seems ;) )

Comment: use the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068185/ubuntu-haskell-ghci-7-4-1-could-not-find-module-system-random, except the package is https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.7.

Comment: (@DanielWagner I made a mess, sorry. voted to reopen, then voted to close for lack of details, then wanted to vote to close it back as your dup so retracted, and now the system won't let me vote on it at all....)

Answer (score 0):

At this point we have no information about the `Card` and `Deck` data types.

However, it seems that the problem at hand is to *randomly* extract M cards from an initial deck of N cards.

If this interpretation of the question is correct, we can thus use the `Rand` monad constructor, and start by defining a monadic action that transfers just one card from the right deck to the left deck.

As we have no information about the types in use, we will assume that the “cards” are denoted by plain numbers, from 0 to 51.

Next, we define an action moving M cards recursively, moving one card and then calling ourselves with an (M-1) argument. For M=0, we define the action as a no-op.

This would be the monadic code:

```
import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random


moveOneCardLeft :: RandomGen g => ([a],[a]) -> Rand g ([a],[a])
moveOneCardLeft (deck, rest) =
    do
        let  remCount = length rest
        choice <- getRandomR (0, (remCount-1))
        let  (top, bot) = splitAt choice rest
        return $ ((head bot) : deck, top ++ (tail bot))


moveSomeCardsLeft :: RandomGen g => Int -> ([a],[a]) -> Rand g ([a],[a])
moveSomeCardsLeft 0 (deck, rest) = return (deck, rest)  -- unchanged
moveSomeCardsLeft n (deck, rest) =
    do
        (deck1, rest1) <- moveOneCardLeft (deck, rest)
        (deck2, rest2) <- moveSomeCardsLeft (n-1) (deck1, rest1)
        return (deck2, rest2)


extractSomeCards :: RandomGen g => Int -> [a] -> Rand g ([a], [a])
extractSomeCards n xs =
    do
        (deck, rest) <- moveSomeCardsLeft n ([], xs)
        return (deck, rest)
```

Next, the *pure* code and some tentative game-related utility functions:

```
drawSomeCards :: RandomGen g => g -> Int -> [a] -> (([a], [a]), g)
drawSomeCards gen0 n xs = runRand (extractSomeCards n xs) gen0

cardValue :: Int -> Int
cardValue n = let rank = mod n 13
              in  if (rank < 10) then (rank+1)
                                 else {- Jack Queen King -} 10

deckValue :: [Int] -> Int
deckValue cards = sum (map cardValue cards)

totalOfCards :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
totalOfCards cards =
    let  s = deckValue cards
    in   if (s <= 21)  then  (Just s)  else  Nothing
```

Finally, the user test code:

```
main = do
    let  wholeDeck  = [0..51]
         randomSeed = 4243
         gen0 = mkStdGen randomSeed
    putStrLn "How many cards ?"
    inLine <- getLine
    let count = (read inLine :: Int)
    putStrLn $ "Want to extract " ++ (show count) ++ " cards."

    let  ((deck, rest), gen1) = drawSomeCards gen0 count wholeDeck
         sumw = sum wholeDeck
         suma = sum deck
         sumb = sum rest
         sum0 = (suma + sumb) - sumw
    putStrLn $ "Must be zero: " ++ (show sum0)   -- sanity check
    putStrLn $ "deck: " ++ (show deck)
    putStrLn $ "rest: " ++ (show rest)
    putStrLn $ "Deck value: " ++ (show $ deckValue deck)
```

### Program execution:

```
$ q67025780.x
How many cards ?
10
Want to extract 10 cards.
Must be zero: 0
deck: [8,47,38,49,4,31,9,30,28,23]
rest: [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,29,32,33,34,35,36,37,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,48,50,51]
Deck value: 77
$
```

**Note:** if deemed appropriate, the above code beyond `moveOneCardLeft` can be simplified using the `nest :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a` function from the [Control.Monad.HT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.16/docs/Control-Monad-HT.html#v:nest) package.

Like this:

```
import  Control.Monad.HT  (nest)

moveOneCardLeft :: RandomGen g => ([a],[a]) -> Rand g ([a],[a])
moveOneCardLeft (deck, rest) =
    do
        let  remCount = length rest
        choice <- getRandomR (0, (remCount-1))
        let  (top, bot) = splitAt choice rest
        return $ ((head bot) : deck, top ++ (tail bot))

drawSomeCards :: RandomGen g => g -> Int -> [a] -> (([a], [a]), g)
drawSomeCards gen0 n xs = let action = nest n moveOneCardLeft ([], xs)
                          in  runRand action gen0
```