# How can I select a random subsequence of length 'l' in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, random

I have a list of vertices [1..n] and I need to select a random subsequence of  the vertices of length 'l'.

`Eg : generateS 3 [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`

`Answer = [5,11,13]`

Is there any better way than:

```
sort (take 5 $ randomRs (70,100) (mkStdGen 3) :: [Int]  )
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: no clue where to start.

Comment: then you should start with a simpler task: for example take a list and make a list of 2-tuples where the first item of the tuple is an element, and the second the rest of the elements.

Comment: voting to close, no effort.

Comment: tried this sort (take 5 $ randomRs (70,100) (mkStdGen 3) :: [Int]  ) any better way to do ?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129886/a-faster-way-of-generating-combinations-with-a-given-length-preserving-the-orde).

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Possibly related, but in the context of card games: [SO-q67025780](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025780/how-can-i-draw-that-number-of-cards-from-a-deck-in-haskell). Note that keeping order in the extracted subsequence is not really needed. It is good enough to use `zip [0..] xs` instead of plain `xs`, and ultimately to use `sort` on the extracted subsequence, leveraging the default lexicographic order on pairs.

Answer (score 3):

The gold standard algorithm for this problem is [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).